# HBase Filtering Rows

Tags: java, mapreduce, hbase

I have an HBase table in which when new data is added, one column family is not included(data is processed and persisted later).

A batch job need to filter in these news Rows which don't have values for this particular column, fetch them , calculate and update the column which was not earlier there.

Initially I expected hbase to provide a filtering mechanism to get all the rows which doesn't have value defined to a specific CF, but it seems hbase doesn't work that way.

```
KEY | CF1 | CF2 | CF3|
A     11     11    11
B     22     22          <-- I need to get these rows.
C     33     33          <-- I need to get these rows.
D     44     44    44
```

What will be the optimal approach to solve this problem?